# TASM outputs result of multiplication as ascii symbol, how to convert to integer

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

The purpose of this program made in TASM is to multiply two single digit numbers and write the result on the screen. What it does it actually multiply, but the result is shown as ascii symbol (i checked with this site http://chexed.com/ComputerTips/asciicodes.php and the results are correct). I cant get it to show result as integer, especially when result is two digit number.

```
.model small
.stack
```

.data

```
msgA DB "Input 1st number: $"
msgB DB 10, 13, "Input 2nd number $"
msgC DB 10, 13, 10, 13, "Result: $"
msgD DB 10, 13, 10, 13, "Error, retry", 10, 13, 10, 13, "$"
```

.code

MOV AX, @DATA
MOV DS, AX

`jmp start

num1 DB ?
num2 DB ?
result Dw ?


start:

    mov ah, 09              
    mov dx, offset msgA
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    mov num1, al

    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, offset msgB
    int 21h

    mov ah, 01
    int 21h
    mov num2, al


    mov al,num1         
    sub al,'0'
    mov bl,num2
    sub bl,'0'
    mul bl
    add ax,'0'

    mov result, ax
    sub result, 48

    mov ah, 09
    mov dx, offset msgC
    int 21h

    mov ah, 02
    mov dx, result
    int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h
end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to convert the integer result to a string, which you then can print using `int 21h / ah = 9`.

A simple way of doing the conversion is as follows (I'll let you do the translation to TASM-syntax x86 assembly):

```
ax = the value to convert
si = &buffer[9];     // buffer is an array of at least 10 bytes
buffer[9] = '$';     // DOS string terminator
do {
    ax /= 10;
    si--;            // the buffer is filled from right to left
    *si = dl + '0';  // place the remainder + '0' in the buffer
} while (ax != 0);
dx = si;             // dx now points to the first character of the string
```

Comment: I did it a bit different, but it works like charm. I found that that result is saved in al and ah so i changed the code that it outputs both of these, thanks for help :)